# Write a PostgreSQL extension that makes use of PostGIS internal methods?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

As I've just found out, it is possible to extend PostgreSQL with custom functions written in C. And I also now know that that's how PostGIS itself is written. However what if I want to build on top of PostGIS methods, is it possible? So, like, write an extension that would make use of some of the PostGIS internal methods?

Comment: PostGIS is open source, so you have access to the internal methods whether or not they're exposed by the DLL.

Comment: By including it's source into my extension or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Probably best to leave the PostGIS source in its own tree, and access either the DLL or the library or the source as necessary.